# Dealing with 100+ categories

Tags: channel-entries, categories, control-panel

I need a 'location_channel' with location entries.
These entries should have 3 multi-select boxes containing different categories.

**Select #1 - Location Type**

- Education

  - Academies
  - Auditoria
  - ...
- Religion

  - Chapels
  - Temples
  - ...
- ...

**Select #2 - Location Style**

- Medieval
- Gothic
- ...

**Select #3 - Location Era**

- 10th Century
- 11th Century
- ...

I tried to do this with native EE categories, but it seems it's not possible to add multiple 'categories'-fields. And it wouldn't be easily selectable when you have 100+ categories.

Also looked at Playa, but it handles entries not categories.

**So my question is:**
What is the best way/practice to handle this case?
Am I overlooking something to do this with native categories?
Should I make use of a category_channel & add the 'categories' as channel_entries?
Or should I use 'Tags' instead?

**Keep in mind:**

- easily manageable by the admin
- only the admin can add/remove categories
- on the front we need a 'search/filter' that can handle these categories

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but it seems it's not possible to add multiple 'categories'-fields.

I'm not sure I'm reading that right though, you can add multiple category groups.

If you go to Admin > Channel Administration > Channels > Edit Group Assignments

Where "Edit Group Assignments" being the link to where you can assign category groups, statuses and a channel field group to a certain channel.

You can then select multiple category groups by ctrl/cmd clicking multiple category groups at once and  updating.

You also mentioned multi-select boxes and I remember there being an add-on which would setup the native category "tree" into multi-selects though, for the life of me I can't remember what it was called and if it was for EE1 or EE2.

There are a few category field types which may come in handy:

- http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wb-category-select
- http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/jp-category-select

As far as using one of the Tag add-ons I'm not sure you can get tags within tags if that makes sense. So from your example:

- Location Type

  - Education

    - Academies

Comment: Aha! I knew it had to be something simple I've overlooked!  
My next question was going to be how to 'collapse' the native category "tree" (because the list is very long), but it seems like you're a step ahead :)  
Thanks @Natetronn!

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)